# Access transcriptionText from twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-twiml

I want to access the transcription text that has been generated by transcribe in my Twilio account under transcriptions as I want to compare user recorded response as text

```
twiml.say('Hi there! Please speak your response after the beep,-Get ready!')
        .record({
            transcribe:true,
            timeout:5,
            maxLength:30,
            transcribeCallback:'/recording',
            action:'/recording'

        });
app.post('/recording', (request,response) => {
if(transcriptionText=='yes'){

    twiml.say('thank you for positive response');
}
  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When using [transcription](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-transcribe) with [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record), once the recording is complete the call will continue on to make a request to the `action` attribute synchronously. Whatever you return from the `action` attribute URL will control the call.

The actual transcription, however, takes a bit more time and when you get a webhook to the `transcribeCallback` URL it is done asynchronously, outside the context of the call. So, returning TwiML will not affect the call at all.

You will get the transcription text by inspecting the body of the request. There are plenty of [parameters sent to the `transcribeCallback`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-transcribecallback-parameters), but the one you are looking for is the `TranscriptionText`. In your Node.js app, which looks like Express to me, you can get hold of it by calling `request.body.TranscriptionText`.

If you do want to affect the call when you receive the transcribe callback you will need to [use the REST API to modify the call and redirect it to some new TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state).

Let me know if that helps at all.

**[edit]**

From the comments I can see you are trying to drive a part of the call from a spoken response. The `transcribeCallback` URL isn't called immediately as the transcription needs to be done, so you need an `action` URL that you can send your caller to while you wait.

So, adjust your recording route to have different endpoints for `action` and `transcribeCallback`:

```
app.post("/voice", (request, response) => {
  var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
  twiml.say('Hi there! Please speak your response after the beep,-Get ready!')
    .record({
      transcribe:true,
      timeout:5,
      maxLength:30,
      transcribeCallback:'/transcribe',
      action:'/recording'
  });
  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());
})
```

Then your recording endpoint will need to keep the user waiting while Twilio transcribes the text.

```
app.post('/recording', (request,response) => {
  var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
  // A message for the user
  twiml.say('Please wait while we transcribe your answer.');
  twiml.pause();
  // Then redirect around again while we wait
  twiml.redirect('/recording');
  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

Finally, when you get the transcribe callback you can figure out the course from the transcribed text somehow and then redirect the live call into a new endpoint that carries on the call with the new information.

```
app.post('/transcribe', (request, response) => {
  var text = request.body.TranscriptionText;
  var callSid = require.body.CallSid;

  // Do something with the text
  var courseId = getCourseFromText(text);

  var accountSid = '{{ account_sid }}'; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
  var authToken = '{{ auth_token }}';   // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console
  var client = new twilio.RestClient(accountSid, authToken);

  // Redirect the call
  client.calls(callSid).update({
    url: '/course?courseId=' + courseId,
    method: 'POST'
  }, (err, res) => {
    response.sendStatus(200);
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, My transcribcallback and action url are same ie /recording but in /recording when I get request.body.TranscriptionText into a variable and I pass it to twiml.say it says undefined. I can access request.body.recordingUrl but nothing releted to Transcription I don't want to break the flow of my voice system as I want to use transcrib text as user input and then compare it with my mongodb for next twiml respons, please help

Comment: The transcription takes a short while, so isn't part of the first callback to the `action` URL. You will get another callback to that URL with the transcription text, however that can't, as I said, directly affect the call. For that reason I'd advise using a different URL to make that obvious in your app. If you want to affect the call from the asynchronous transcribeCallback then you will need to use the REST API as I said in my original answer.

Comment: What changes should I do in my code for accessing request.body.transcriptionText to be with the value that user currently spoke. What should be my trascribcallback url ? I am very new into this so it's difficult to understand

Comment: thanks a ton ill try this, but how will it get out of /recording loop

Comment: By redirecting the call from the REST API, in the last part of the final code block above.

Comment: I tried your solution it keep gets looping in /recording and does not come in /transcribe

Comment: Are you getting the transcribe callback?

Comment: app.post('/transcribe', (request, response) => {
  var text = request.body.TranscriptionText;
  var callSid = request.body.CallSid;
  var courseId =text;
 var accountSid = ''; 
    var authToken = '';  
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
  client.calls(callSid).update({
    url: '/course?courseId=' + courseId,
    method: 'POST'
  }, (err, res) => {
    response.sendStatus(200);
  })
});

Comment: app.post('/course', (request,response) => {
var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
    var courseId = request.param('courseId');
      twiml.say('hello'+courseId);
  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());
});

Comment: I mean, are you getting any requests to your transcribe endpoint? Is something failing in the API request? Is there anything in the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger)?

Comment: do i need to include transcribe call back url in my twilio account somewhere?

Comment: No, just as the `transcribeCallback` in the `<Record>` TwiML

Comment: there is no error log in debugger and text is transcribed in twilio transcription log

Comment: Are you getting a request to the `transcribeCallback` endpoint though?

Comment: No Request Inspector does not show request to transcribeCallback

Comment: If you are not getting the callbacks, then I'd recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and supplying them with call SIDs for the calls you've tried that had transcriptions. You should receive the transcription callback, though you may have to wait a bit for it to come through, it depends on how long the transcription itself takes.

Comment: You don't want to redirect to /transcribe. Twilio should send an HTTP request to /transcribe when the transcription is complete.

Comment: app.post('/recording', (request,response) => {
  var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
  // A message for the user
   for(var i = 0; i<= 5; i++) {
        twiml.say('Please wait while we transcribe your answer.');
  twiml.pause(
     {
     length:"2"
     }
  
  );
  // Then redirect around again while we wait
 
}
     twiml.redirect('/transcribe');

  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());
});  I tried this it gives me a response of OK you have any idea why is this so

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve with that, but you should be letting Twilio make the call to /transcribe once the transcription of the message is done.

Comment: Got you, but /recording goes in infinite loop and request to transcribecall back is never executed even after text is converted I don't know what should I do now

Comment: Like I said earlier, if transcriptions are being created but you are not getting the webhook then you should contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and give them Call SIDs for the calls in which the transcription endpoint wasn't called. They will be able to find out why it's not getting called.

Comment: i tried solution

`var twilio = require('twilio');`
`var client = new twilio.RestClient(accountSid, authToken);`

giving me error: `TypeError: twilio.RestClient is not a constructor`

Comment: Don't use the `new` keyword then  Have you checked which version of the Twilio module you have and which version you are viewing on the docs too?